# Android studio edit suggestion menu and what it actually does

Tags: android-studio

When I click `"alt+enter"` using android studio on a value for example, i get this menu [image]

I want to `edit the content` of it, and i want to edit what clicking each line does, because what it does is not what i want, and i have to spend time fixing it.

Is there a way to do it?